# Is there a quick way to go from an "Open Window" dialog to the Desktop folder?

Tags: windows-7

Many times, I need to select a file form my desktop. But it always seems like a bit of a hassle, to navigate from the left-side panel to find the "Desktop" icon.

[image]
Isthere a quick shortcut, to get to the Desktop folder

Comment: Tried **Win + D** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Activate the left pane (from the "file name" box, pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> twice will do that).
- Start typing "desktop".  Within one or two letters it'll be highlighted (depending on how many other entries you have that start with D, followed by E, etc...)
- Press enter to open it.